# Google Maps styles Option Error, when adding one style. Too many styles?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I implemented a Google-Map in a website with custom styles. My custom style works fine until the following element is added:

```
{
  "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
  "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
  "stylers": [{
      "color": "#3d7eff"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the same error, if the array contains this element:

```
{
  "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#000000"
  }]
}
```

The error: `Custom style string for [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], [...]`

See below snippet. If the last element (`poi.sports_complex`) is commented out, it works.

```js
var map;

function initMap() {

  var style = [{
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }]
    },
    {
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#523735"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#b9d3c2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#92998d"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dcd2be"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ae9e90"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dcd2be"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#bebbba"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#d6ffcc"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural.landcover",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#96df87"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#176408"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e3f1c5"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#93817c"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.attraction",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ee9907"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#48c5f2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e2f7d0"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.business",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#360101"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffff00"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.government",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#09015d"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#07eed7"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.medical",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ca0202"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#92c085"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#447530"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f42c0b"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#b8d2ae"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#fdfcf8"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#806b63"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f8c967"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e9bc62"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e98d58"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#db8555"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.line",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#8f7d77"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "transit.station",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#2d3d29"
      }]
    }];

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.369840, 4.797046),
      zoom: 14,
      styles: style
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  }
```

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

**Update**
Seems as if you can use too many styles.
I removed all styles to road, and the code triggered no error with `sports_complex > geometry.stroke` and all the school-styles, which triggered the same error this morning. The same, if I remove the transit styles of the example. Unfortunately `sports_complex > geometry.stroke` is not displayed even if I set `weight: 2`.
Since I can't find any hint about a maximum of styles in the documention, it might be a bug.

Comment: Looks like a bug really. I have seen a few weird things happening with these styles. Changing the order of some of the features sometimes works. Your code doesn't trigger the error if you only use `sports.complex` > `geometry` and `geometry_stroke` without any other style. Or with your complete array but without `poi` > `geometry`. Anyway I tested it and geometry stroke on sports complex doesn't seem to ever have any effect in any case. Which is probably another bug. It doesn't even work with the cloud based map styling.

Comment: It might be worth reporting in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853). Here is a [mcve](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/fg6ncmL3/) that shows no error but no stroke.

Comment: Changing the order had no effect. The styles are created by a function from an array, and I moved it to the end, to check if they are created wrong.

Comment: I also wonder what the error message `Custom style string for [object Object]` means. Thanks

Comment: You should report it really. And cross-link your question with your reported issue.